# Running a Theory runs other Facts in xunit.net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am using `xunit.net 2.1.0` with visual studio 2013 ultimate.
I have a `Theory` and several `Facts`. When I run the `Theory` other `Facts` run too.How can I run only the theory.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the Theory"? in the test explorer, if you select only the theory (or you right click inside the theory code), it should run **only** it

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? I had a similar bug with R#'s XUnit runner that's going to be fixed in the next update. Also, are the results of the `Facts` being taken into account as the test result?

Comment: Yes. I am using ReSharper 8.0.2. Other Facts are running seperately
@LukeW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you're using ReSharper I'd say it's a bug in the ReSharper XUnit runner. I ran into a similar bug where `Fact` would run `Theory`.
This bug will be fixed in the ReSharper 10.1 support (see [here](https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/issues/117)) although ReSharper 10.1, now called 2016.1, will have built in XUnit support that may also fix this.

If it's causing an issue run the tests from command line or using Visual Studios XUnit runner which is on NuGet ([xunit.runner.visualstudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio)).